# Is it possible to block/wait an already existing asynchronous function?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-threads

```
SomeLibrary lib = new SomeLibrary();
lib.doSomethingAsync(); // some function from a library I got and what it does is print 1-5 asynchronously
System.out.println("Done");

// output
// Done
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

I want to be clear that I didn't make the `doSomethingAsync()` function and it's out of my ability to change it. I want to find a way to block this async function and print `Done` after the numbers 1 to 5 because as you see `Done` is being instantly printed. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: What does `doSomethingAsync()` return? If it's void, then you're out of luck.

Comment: Have you tried `lib.doSomethingAsync().join()`?

Comment: @ZahidKhan join() does not exist for `lib.doSomethingAsync()`

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: you could observe whatever that method is doing and wait until it happens. If you could provide more details about what that method does, we can help better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountDownLatch` as follow:

```
final CountDownLatch wait = new CountDownLatch(1);
SomeLibrary lib = new SomeLibrary(wait);
lib.doSomethingAsync(); // some function from a library I got and what it does is print 1-5 asynchronously
//NOTE in the doSomethingAsync, you must call wait.countDown() before return
wait.await(); //-> it wait in here until wait.countDown() is called.
System.out.println("Done");
```

In Constructor `SomeLibrary` :

```
private CountDownLatch  wait;
public ScannerTest(CountDownLatch  _wait) {
    this.wait = _wait;
}
```

In method `doSomethingAsync()`:

```
public void doSomethingAsync(){
   //TODO something
   ...
   this.wait.countDown();
   return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry @TruongNguyen but I said I cannot modify the said function/library.

Comment: Oh, can you share the info of SomeLibrary (others method, supper class of it, ...) and info of doSomethingAsync (return type).

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved in a couple of ways in standard libraries :-

**Completion Callback**

Clients can often provider function to be invoked after the async task is complete. This function usually receives some information regarding the work done as it's input.

**Future.get()**

Async functions return `Future` for client synchronization. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Do check if any of these options are available (perhaps, an overloaded version ?_ in the method you wish to invoke. It is not too uncommon for libraries to include both sync and async version of some business logic so you could search for that too.